# IOUSBInterfaceInterface Already Open

Tags: macos, serial-port, usb, driver, iokit

I am trying to intercept/interact with a Maschine Mikro 2 plugged into my Mac via USB. I have a `IOUSBInterfaceInterface` reference to the correct USB HID interface. However, whenever I try to call, `USBInterfaceOpen` on the interface, I always get the `IOReturn` value of 0x2c5, meaning another program already has exclusive access to this interface.

The only other program I could think of that would have this interface open is the Native Instruments device driver since it would need to write to this interface. However, if the driver has exclusive access to the interface, how is any other program supposed to read from it?

Does anyone have experience with the Native Instruments drivers and know how they expose the device to user-space? I would've expected a file of the form `/dev/cu.*` but none are created when the Mikro 2 is plugged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out there is a daemon called `NIHardwareAgent` that I believe has exclusive access to the USB interface. Through reverse engineering the Maschine 2 app, I found that it communicates with the hardware agent through `CFMessagePort`'s.